# Apache Ant Profiler

Tags: ant, profiling, profiler

Is there an `Ant` profiler that will run my ant script and tell me how long targets, tasks and operations took to complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ant has two related features to allow the build process to be monitored => [listeners and loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) :

- Ant >= 1.8.x ships with the [ProfileLogger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#ProfileLogger)
- [Ant statistics](http://code.google.com/p/antstatistics/), a logger that logs executions times for all targets, and graphs them over the time
- [Performance Monitor from antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/performance_monitor.html), a listener that keeps track of the amount of time that each target and task takes to execute and prints a final summary

or [write your own](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#buildevents).

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for. I went with the `antcontrib` version. I already had `antcontrib` so it seemed easiest.

Comment: Antstatistics is now on Github.

Answer (score -1):

YourKit YouMonitor is able to profile Ant, Maven, Gradle and many other build tools https://www.yourkit.com/youmonitor/

disclaimer: I work for YourKit